# react-web-ar - Rendering component containing AFrameRenderer gives Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe, artoolkit, aframe-react

I have two components `Home.js` and `View.js`.
My `View.js` returns a JSX with `AframeRenderer` tag.
I want to render the `View.js` component whenever user clicks the `Click Me` option in the `Home.js` component.

Below is the snapshot of the codes from `App.js`, `Home.js` and `View.js`

The code gives error whenever the website tries to open `localhost:3000/view` page

The error says as follows:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `View`.

**`App.js`:**

```
import Home from './Home/Home'
import View from './View/View'

class App extends Component {
        render() {
                return(
                        <BrowserRouter>
                                <div className = "App">
                                        <Switch>
                                                <Route path = '/' exact component = {Home} />
                                                <Route path = '/view' exact component = {View} />
                                        </Switch>
                                </div>
                        
                        </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**`Home.js`:**

```
import View from '../View/View'

class Home extends Component{
        render() {
                return (
                        <Link to =  { {
                                pathname: '/view/'
                          } } >
                            Click Me
                        </Link>
                );
        }
}
export default Home;
```

**`View.js`:**

```
class View extends Component {
        render() {
                return (
                        <AFrameRenderer arToolKit = {{sourceType: 'webcam'} } >
                                <Marker parameters = {{ preset : 'hiro'}} >
                                        <a-box color="blue" material = "opacity: 1;"position="0 0.9 0" scale="0.4 0.8 0.8">
                                                <a-animation attribute="rotation" to="360 0 0" dur="5000" easing="linear" repeat = "indefinite" />
                                        </a-box>
                                </Marker>
                        </AFrameRenderer>
                );
        }
}

export default View;
```